# FPDF Código de Barras Code128 Erro

Tags: php, php-7, fpdf

Estou tentando gerar um arquivo PDF usando o FPDF e uma classe ***"Code 128 barcodes"*** (encontrei em fpdf.org > scripts > Code 128 barcodes).
O método `Code128()` está dentro do arquivo **code128.php** na classe `class PDF_Code128 extends FPDF`

Porém, quando tento usar meu código recebo erro na página de que já existe este método sendo usado e não consigo gerar o PDF.

Segue meu código até então:

```
require("../fpdf/fpdf.php");
require("../fpdf/code128.php");

$pdf=new PDF_Code128();
$pdf->AddPage("L", array(54,86));
$pdf->AddFont('Univers','','univers.php');
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);
$pdf->Image("../img/modeloArquivo.png", 0, 0, 86, 54);

$nome='Teste';
$pdf->SetFont('Univers', '', '6');
$pdf->SetXY(28.8,17);
$pdf->Write(6, $nome);

$local='Teste';
$pdf->SetFont('Univers', '', '6');
$pdf->SetXY(28.8,23);
$pdf->Write(6, $local);
```

Comment: Cheque os require do seu arquivo e as classes, parece que a classe do PDF_Code128 extende a classe do FPDF e pode ser que esteja chamando algum método duas vezes.

Answer (score -1):

Chequei o que foi colocado ali nos comentários e foi isso mesmo que resolveu. Quando eu tirava o `require("../fpdf/fpdf.php");` desde arquivo não funcionava também, mas porque eu não havia visto o require no arquivo ***code128.php***.
Atualizei o require neste arquivo (por padrão vem: `require("../fpdf.php");` e no meu site estou usando `require("../fpdf/fpdf.php");`) e removi do meu arquivo principal, deixando nele apenas o `require("../fpdf/code128.php");` e parou de dar conflitos entre os métodos do Code128 e do FPDF.